# C# code to save the zoomed image on picturebox control in windows mobile App

Tags: c#, windows-mobile

I capture a image from windows mobile camera and save it on 
picturebox control..now to zoom the picture i am increasing 
its size by Onpaint event.The image is getting zoomed but
i am not able to save the zoomed image(ie.., the increased
image size)...

Please let me know

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you have a Bitmap being displayed in the PictureBox? If so, then do this:

```
Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)myPictureBox.Image;
bmp.Save("\My Documents\My Pictures\image.jpg", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```